# Jquery does not work on Ajax generated HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

my JavaScript doesnot work after i sort my products page with ajax and overwrite existed DOM elements with newly generated DOM by ajax. All effect are gone when i sort products like zoom product images etc. I read different articles which tells me that i should use .on to bind my DOM but .on does not work in case. Below i show the code

> ```
> $(document).ready(function (){
>
>             function callAjax (){
>
>                 if ($("#brandId").val() == "")
>                 {
>                     var brandId;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     var brandId = $("#brandId").val();
>                 }
>                 if ($("#categoryId").val() == "")
>                 {
>                     var categoryId;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     var categoryId = $("#categoryId").val();
>                 }
>                 if ($("#genderId").val() == "")
>                 {
>                     var genderId;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     var genderId = $("#genderId").val();
>                 }
>                 if ($("#stockId").val() == "")
>                 {
>                     var stockId;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     var stockId = $("#stockId").val();
>                 }
>
>                 $.ajax({
>                     url: baseUrlForExternalJS.baseUrl + "site/sort_products",
>                     type:"POST",
>                     data: {'brandId':brandId, 'categoryId' : categoryId, 'genderId' : genderId , 'stockId' : stockId },
>                     success: function(msg){
>                         $('#products').html(msg);
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
>
>             $("#categoryId").on('change', function(){
>                 //alert('called');
>                 callAjax();
>             });
>             $("#genderId").on('change', function(){
>                 //alert('called');
>                 callAjax();
>             });
>             $("#stockId").on('change', function(){
>                 //alert('called');
>                 callAjax();
>             });
>
>             $("#brandId").on('change', function(){
>                 callAjax();
>             })
>
>         });
>  </script>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Use a delegated event handler, and all the if/else conditions are not neccessary, nor the seperate event handlers that all do the same thing :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function callAjax() {
        var brandId    = $("#brandId").val(),
            categoryId = $("#categoryId").val(),
            genderId   = $("#genderId").val(),
            stockId    = $("#stockId").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrlForExternalJS.baseUrl + "site/sort_products",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                brandId    : brandId,
                categoryId : categoryId,
                genderId   : genderId,
                stockId    : stockId
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            $('#products').html(msg);
        });
    }

    $('#products').on('change', '#categoryId, #genderId, #stockId, #brandId', callAjax);
});
```

You could also build the data from the ID's and create something a little neater, something like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elems = ['categoryId', 'genderId', 'stockId', 'brandId'];

    $('#products').on('change', '#'+elems.join(',#'), function() {
        var data = {};
        $.each(elems, function(_,id) {data[id] = document.getElementById(id).value;});
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrlForExternalJS.baseUrl + "site/sort_products",
            type: "POST",
            data: data
        }).done(function (msg) {
            $('#products').html(msg);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend `$()` over `$(document).ready()` and `$.post()` over `$.ajax({type: "POST"})`.

Comment: Also the second example has a small bug - `data` should be declared in the event handler. not in the closure. And it can be made even simpler. http://pastebin.com/V6i9DgCp

Comment: @Tomalak - that's a nice example and the code looks a lot better too. I didn't really spend that much time on it, it just immediately looked like something that could be done much simpler than the OP's code.

Comment: I did move the data variable, thanks, as that could have caused errors on subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code to:

```
 $('#products').on('change',"#categoryId", function(){
                //alert('called');
                callAjax();
            });

//like wise change for all remaining.
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I did as you said, but when i switch ma code with you, it didn't send a Ajax request to server.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is wrong here.

For dynamic elements, you need event propagation based event handlers, for that you need to use a different syntax

like

```
$(document).on('<event>', '<selector>', handler)
```

Ex

```
        $(document).on('change', '"#stockId"', function(){
            //alert('called');
            callAjax();
        })
```

Comment: still facing the same problem. I correct my code as you shown, but still it don't work. All my effect are gone after sorting my products.

Answer (score 0):

If the id's you are using for effects should be available when the document gets ready, Also, You need to call the function after you update the content via ajax I guess.

But better move your effects and animations to a function and ajax post to another function 
then call it on document ready and after the ajax success.

You can debug in a better way. And you can avoid similar bugs.

If you can give your full code, I can try to debug it for you.

Comment: I hope its about helping and not violating the terms. You can zip and send to ggokul.89@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but I found the answer.

Just like the above people have said. You .on() function will do the trick.

On the jQuery website [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().** To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

Which means that if you are calling ajax code (event handlers that weren't there when the code was loaded) you need to bind it to an element that was there.

Here is an example:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "p", function() {
    alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

You can see that on the link above too. There it shows how it works.